# Does anyone have a suitable Windows/Mac keyboard mapping shortcut reference?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, cross-reference

I'm looking for a Windows to Mac keyboard shortcut reference.

For example:

In Windows, 'highlight to end of current line' is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>. What is the Mac equivalent?

[This Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) doesn't seem to have them all, as well as [this Ultimate Switcher guide](http://www.myfirstmac.com/index.php/mac/articles/ultimate-switcher-guide-windows-pc-to-mac-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: I thought [Apple's own list](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) was pretty good.

Comment: @slhck You should post this as answer.

Comment: @Daniel Well, technically it's not a Windows → Mac list.

Comment: @slhck True. But still, how many shortcuts can there be? Also, a *Windows —> Mac* mapping, depending on the format, loses all shortcuts that are unique to OS X... some aren't as easily translatable, although possible, e.g. *Windows-L* for locking the screen.

Comment: I used the page linked by slhck as a starting point for http://cs.helsinki.fi/u/lranta/shortcuts/osx.txt. Text editing shortcuts: [Cocoa Text System - Default System Key Bindings](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html)